# Default Browser- Visual Web Developer Express 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, visual-web-developer

I am trying to debug a Windows Azure WebRole which is an MVC3 project, but I want it to launch in any browser of my choice.

The Windows Azure is set as the Startup Project and launches the MVC3 project WebRole.

I am using Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2010.

I have previously stabbed in the dark by setting the following properties as in the image below but to no avail:

[image: ProjectPropertyPages_WebTab]

I then decided to set the project to not independently launch a page as above.

Is there a way to setup a default browser with the above scenario **AND** without changing my Windows default browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've gotten around this in the past by adding in an ASPX or HTML page to the project and then right clicking it and selecting Browse With. You can then change the default browser in there without having to change your default browser within windows.

I haven't tried this with the Express edition however, but I don't see why they wouldn't include it in there.

You can delete the file afterwards and it will still retain the setting.

Comment: mmmmm tricksy! good idea. will give that a try when I get home and post some comments about it :-)

Comment: wow. it worked! thanks. wish ms allowed some proper extensions to the express editions. nevertheless, this seems to be the easiest way i've come across that works.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:
WoVS Default Browser Switcher
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921

Comment: I use this with the proper/full version- Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Does this also work with **Visual Studio 2010 Web Developer Express** ?

Comment: sorry, don't know, probably, as it is mainly a tool for web devs

Comment: @Tim- Tried it and it does not work. I get an error that reads "This extension is not extensible on any currently installed products". Since the extensibility of the Express Editions of VS is very limited, I'm not surprised it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You right on the page shown in solution explorer and then browse with whatever browser you want to set and add it as default browser.